# recyclerview's notifyItemInserted inserting in wrong position

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which is reverseLayout,
I add items to my recyclerview one by one in a loop which is running inside a handler.postDelay.
I add each item at position 0 because I want the new item to be added in the bottom of my list and the rest of the list pushes up. 
but when my list grows, it adds new items to irrelevant positions too. here is the code:

```
private void setRecyclerview() {
    i = 0;
    adapterConversation = new AdapterConversation(this, temp.get(i));
    recyclerviewConversation.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
            RecyclerView.VERTICAL, true));
    recyclerviewConversation.setAdapter(adapterConversation);
    adapterConversation.addItem(1, temp.get(i));
    adapterConversation.notifyItemInserted(0);
    time = temp.get(i).getStart_at();
    i++;
    setHandler();
}
```

and here is my handler:

```
 private void setHandler() {
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, time);
    runnable = () -> {
        if (i == temp.size()) {
            finish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (i < temp.size() && !isPaused && (temp.get(i).getStart_at()) * 1000 < player.getCurrentPosition()) {
            adapterConversation.addItem(1, temp.get(i));
            //adapterConversation.notifyItemInserted(adapterConversation.getItemCount() - (i + 1));
            adapterConversation.notifyItemInserted(0);
            recyclerviewConversation.scrollToPosition(0);
            i++;
            if (i < temp.size()) {
                time = temp.get(i).getStart_at();
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, time);
    };
    runnable.run();
}
```

and in my Adapter:

```
public AdapterConversation(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.itemCount = 0;
}

public void addItem(int item, LessonDetailText lessonDetailText) {

    itemCount += item;
    lessonDetailTextList.add(lessonDetailText);
}
```

*when my list grows, older items in the list change and they get new values (which is the latest value added), but I don't call "notifyDataSetChange"
does anyone know why this happens? is this "notifyItemInserted" inserting in wrong position?*

help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `notifyDataSetChange`& `notifyItemInserted` calls, are `BaseAdapter` methods . Which means that calling them will not "insert" anything to your list that you are trying to display. They just [notify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) any observer that new items added in the list and update the views.

It seems in your code that you are always adding an item to a specific position. Because you initiate the `int i = 0;` in your `setRecyclerview()` which means that every time the position you are inserting is 0. You dont have  to do all that. Just .add new items to your list and set use the `LinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true)` , to display from the bottom of the view.